# как вывести данные из файла json на html страницу

Tags: java, json, spring

код в файле textExit.html выглядит вот так

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test Exit</title>
</head>
<body>
Test Finished!
</body>
</html>
```

у меня есть файл results.json c такими данными

```
[{"question":"Question27","level":5,"answer":{"text":""},"checkResult":false},{"question":"Question28","level":5,"answer":{"text":""},"checkResult":false},{"question":"Question16","level":4,"answer":{"text":""},"checkResult":false},{"question":"Question13","level":4,"answer":{"text":""},"checkResult":false},{"question":"Question7","level":3,"answer":{"text":""},"checkResult":false},{"question":"Question8","level":3,"answer":{"text":""},"checkResult":false},{"question":"Question3","level":2,"answer":{"text":""},"checkResult":false},{"question":"Question6","level":2,"answer":{"text":""},"checkResult":false},{"question":"Question1","level":1,"answer":{"text":""},"checkResult":false},{"question":"Question1","level":1,"answer":{"text":""},"checkResult":false}]
```

я хочу вывести их на html страницу textExit
подскажите пожалуйста как это можно сделать, я только начинаю изучать spring

файл results.json находится в папке src/main/resources/static/results.json т.е в самой среде разработки, мне нужно как текст вывести типа: Question 1: What is your name? check result: true

Comment: Из Вашего вопроса ничего непонятно. У Вас result.json где? На стороне сервера, клиента, или он Ваш через AJAX на стороне клиента приходит? textExit - что это и где вообще находится? Весь json необходимо вывести как текст, как узлы или какой-то конкретный узел? И не публикуйте кода скриншотами.

Comment: @XelaNimed 
файл находится в папке src/main/resources/static/results.json
т.е в самой среде разработки, мне нужно как текст вывести
типа: 
Question 1: What is your name?
check result: true

Comment: Добавляйте уточнения в вопрос, а не в комментарии. Замените скриншоты кодом. Как мне кажется, Вам необходимо создать класс описывающий вопросы, в который нужно десериализовать JSON и полученный массив/список экземпляров использовать в шаблоне HTML. Со Spring'ом не знаком, но алгоритм скорее всего будет такой.